# Exclude vice-versa entries from result set using sql query

Tags: sql

Let suppose there four entries in table as shown below.I want only Row 1 and 2 in resultset.
The vice versa case of 1 and 2 in Row 3 and 4 should be excluded. Please suggest a query for that

```
Pk  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1   A       B       20      30
2   E       D       40      50
3   B       A       20      30
4   D       E       40      50
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the criteria for the query?

Comment: Question is so unclear that a trivial answer like `Select * from Table where Pk in (1,2)` is a correct and satisfactory answer. If this does not answer your question, please rephrase it :) `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Table` would also do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE Col1 < Col2` immediately comes to mind. Actually, that would give you rows 1 and 4, but I presume that's good enough for yuor purposes.